# iOS: Create CLLocation with latitude, longitude, speed and timestamp

Tags: ios, cllocation

I'm want to initialize a CLLocation object. To do this I'm using:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

My `location` need speed and timestamp, but speed and timestamp are read only parameters. How can I assign values to this parameters?

Comment: Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:course:speed:timestamp:

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution:

```
initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:course:speed:timestamp:
```

More info: [Apple doc for CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:course:speed:timestamp:).